# Bulk Upload to AWS S3 JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I'm uploading 20k to 30k images to AWS s3 using javascript (aws js sdk). I'm trying to find the best approach to upload the images to s3. Right now I'm just using a simple for loop to initiate the API calls and tracking the progress. This process works well when I upload 100 images but when I upload 20,000 images it hangs the browser, so I'm trying to find a better approach.

My Approaches
1) Using Web workers but setup is more of a headache.

```
let len = files.length;// 20,000
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  aws
    .s3()
    .upload(params, callbackToHandleResponse)
    .on('httpUploadProgress', callbackToHandleProgress)
}
```

Comment: just upload a zip

Comment: What is your use-case for uploading 20,000 files via a browser? Is this for end-users, or for internal use? You couldn't just use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), could you? (Just checking!)

Comment: Hey John, thank you for commenting. This is for end users and we are implementing using CLI and UI.

Comment: @venu would you mind sharing your upload service? I'm having trouble implementing even that :D